# Equivalent of "openssl_encrypt" in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, openssl

I am trying to convert this PHP code to Ruby but the result is not the same. What am I doing wrong?

#### PHP

```php
$iv = str_repeat('0', 16);
$passphrase = str_repeat('0', 32);
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt('Hello', 'AES-256-CBC', $passphrase, 0, $iv);

echo $encrypted; // => lfbW8JcPq6dkEnmY0hG7Vw==
```

#### Ruby

```rb
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').encrypt
cipher.iv = '0' * 16
cipher.key = '0' * 32
encrypted = cipher.update('Hello') + cipher.final

puts encrypted # => \x95\xF6\xD6\xF0\x97\x0F\xAB\xA7d\x12y\x98\xD2\x11\xBBW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Base64#encode64](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) to get the same result as in your php example.

```rb
require 'Base64'
puts Base64.encode64(encrypted) # => lfbW8JcPq6dkEnmY0hG7Vw==
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is basically the same.

If you try to encode AES 256 CBC, you can follow this link : [https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'00000000000000000000000000000000'%7D,%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'0000000000000000'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=SGVsbG8](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%270000000000000000%27%7D,%27CBC%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=SGVsbG8)

As you can see I have encoded "hello" into AES CBC with your Key and IV (both in UTF8)

The result in HEX format is `95f6d6f0970faba764127998d211bb57` which basically matches the Rails string minus the escape sequence `\x`

Now the PHP string is a bit different but it is because it has been BASE 64 encoded.

You can go here https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex and copy `95f6d6f0970faba764127998d211bb57` into the top box, the result will be `lfbW8JcPq6dkEnmY0hG7Vw==`

EDIT

Just notice the Rails string being slightly different to Hex provided by CyberChef in the last characters. Maybe someone can give more details about Rails notation being slightly different than the HEX, together with the escape sequence `\x`. I have read this is common to C language (Ruby is coded in C which may explain the C notation with the `\x`).